# Bhanga and the ego

Tags: vipassana, terminology, meditation-insight

Is the experience of *bhanga* (5th insight - knowledge of dissolution) the equivalent of the destruction of the khandhas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in the knowledge of dissolution the khandas are still there. The Visuddhimagga describes knowledge of dissolution as follows:

> Visuddhimagga XXI (10-11)
>
> When he repeatedly observes in this way, and examines and investigates
>   material and immaterial states, [to see] that they are impermanent,
>   painful, and not-self, then if his knowledge works keenly, formations
>   quickly become apparent. Once his knowledge works keenly and
>   formations quickly become apparent, he no longer extends his
>   mindfulness to their arising or presence or occurrence or sign, but
>   brings it to bear only on their cessation as destruction, fall and
>   breakup.
>
> When insight knowledge has arisen in him in this way so that he sees
>   how the field of formations, having arisen thus, ceases thus, it is
>   called contemplation of dissolution at that stage, 7  with reference
>   to which it is said: “Understanding of contemplation of dissolution,
>   after reflecting on an object— how is this knowledge of insight?
>   “Consciousness  with  materiality  as  its  object  arises  and 
>   dissolves.  Having reflected on that object, he contemplates the
>   dissolution of that consciousness.

In other words, it is called knowledge of dissolution because the mind is focused on seeing the formations break up and cease.

Answer (score 3):

When you reach Bhanga you still have ego. Ego is mainly due to Sanna. To dissolve this you have to look at `contact > sensation > perception > through proliferation > sensations` process and try to stop the thought proliferation / conditioned response of you mind / identification and perception about the world.

With Bhanga you can quickly rid any formation by brining you attention to the sensations associated with Sankhara.